# Why is there a tradeoff between the number of per-thread arenas and memory fragmentation?

Tags: malloc

[From the MallocInternals section of the wiki](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals):

> As pressure from thread collisions increases, additional arenas are created via mmap to relieve the pressure. The number of arenas is capped at eight times the number of CPUs in the system (unless the user specifies otherwise, see mallopt), which means a heavily threaded application will still see some contention, but the trade-off is that there will be less fragmentation.

Why does increasing the number of arenas increase fragmentation? Anecdotally, I've been able to reduce resident set size (*not* just virtual set size) by almost 50% simply by severely restricting memory arenas to just 2 (via MALLOC_ARENA_MAX).

How could a high number of per-thread memory arenas in `malloc` lead to memory fragmentation and an increase in RSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have 300MB to divide up. If you divide it into 8 arenas, you wind up with more "odds and ends" memory, none of it big enough to satisfy a large memory request. The arenas don't dynamically grow or shrink, as a rule. So if you allocate an arena, use up 90% of it and wind up with 10% as fragmentation (nominally waiting to serve small allocations) it doesn't help with your big allocations.

The more arenas you divide it into, the more "odds and ends" memory you wind up with. So: more arenas equals more internal fragmentation.

Comment: This is related to the Chunks. The more chunks, the more (possible) "odds and ends", no matter the number of Arenas. The "large" chunks can be split to avoid those "odds and ends" and thus limit the fragmentation.

Answer (score -1):

The arenas have an internal mutex to lock the memory access from different threads at the same time.

If you have only one arena, only one memory operation is allowed at a time, which decreases fragmentation as new allocations/free are performed.

If you increase the number of arenas, then it means you allow multiple threads to allocate/free the memory at the same time, which creates fragmentation because it is not an atomic operation (see the sections "Malloc Algorithm" and "Free Algorithm")

The 8xCPU rule is there just to leave enough thread concurrency but limit it somehow. 2 arenas *may* (as this is not a fatality) lead to more fragmentation than only 1, so the more arenas, the more fragmentation because more memory operations happen at the same time.

Why does concurrent memory operations lead to fragmentation (oversimplified) : because it becomes harder and harder to allocate contiguous large blocks and freeing little blocks all over does not leave enough space for new large blocks to be allocated there.

So if you restrict the number of arenas, the maintenance job (allocation/free algorithm) is not entering in competition with other arenas running at the same time.

So then, why 8xCPU ? and why not just 2 arenas (as you tested) or even only one ?
This is totally possible to run only 1 arena, but then it means that only one thread is allowed to use the memory at once, hence you loose some performance. If you restrict to 2 arenas, then only 2 threads can use the memory at the same time (one per arena).
And if you have a 4-CPU machine only 2 arenas, only 2 (this is the arena limit) threads can manipulate (via glibc) the memory at the same time which is a waste of resources because only 2 of the CPU are used.

Comment: the "waste of resources" isn't on accessing memory, but only when calling glibc memory functions